# ApplicationUser within an ActionFilter in Asp.Net Core 2.0?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

How can I access the current `ApplicationUser` (or `UserManager`) within an `ActionFilter` in Asp.Net Core 2.0?

I am trying to lock down the entire application until the user accepts the EULA (End User License Agreement), changes their password, and fills out required personal information.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    ...
    public DateTime? DateEULAAccepted { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Here is the `ActionFilter` code:

```
public class ProfileRequiredActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var CurUser = UserManager<ApplicationUser>.GetUserAsync(filterContext.HttpContext.User);
            ...
            if (CurUser.Result.DateEULAAccepted.ToString() == null)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Account", action = "AgreeToEULA" }));
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I am instantiating the `ActionFilter` in the `Startup > ConfigureServices` as follows:

```
...
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new ProfileRequiredActionFilter());
    });
...
```

Comment: Are you injecting the `UserManager` into your `ActionFilter`? What isn't working for you?

Comment: I don't know how to inject the UserManager in... I am instantiating the ActionFilter in Startup ConfigureServices like this:

Comment: services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(new ProfileRequiredActionFilter());
            });

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding your filter in `ConfigureServices()` as follows:

```
services.AddMvc(options => { 
    options.Filters.Add<ProfileRequiredActionFilter>(); 
});
```

You can then inject your `UserManager` into the filter as follows:

```
public class ProfileRequiredActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public ProfileRequiredActionFilter(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var CurUser = _userManager<ApplicationUser>.GetUserAsync(filterContext.HttpContext.User);
            ...
            if (CurUser.Result.DateEULAAccepted.ToString() == null)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Account", action = "AgreeToEULA" }));
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer :)